# Grails Export plugin 1.6 version - xlsx support

Tags: grails, export-to-excel

Does export plugin in grails support the .xlsx format as well? I have given the extension as 'xlsx' and content type as `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`.

I have completed the code and run it without any issues. The issue comes when opening the downloaded file. The file cannot be open as it is (i.e., with xlsx extension'). If I change the extension to 'xls', I am able to open it without any issues.

@EmmanuelRosa, @monty_bean

Grails version:2.0.3
Export plugin version 1.5

Grails configurations

```
grails.mime.types = [
    html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
    text: 'text-plain',
    js: 'text/javascript',
    rss: 'application/rss+xml',
    atom: 'application/atom+xml',
    css: 'text/css',
    csv: 'text/csv',
    pdf: 'application/pdf',
    rtf: 'application/rtf',
    excel: ['application/vnd.ms-excel','application/vnd.openxmlformats-              officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'],
    ods: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    all: '*/*',
    json: ['application/json','text/json'],
    form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
```

]

JS code:

```
window.open("${createLink(controller: 'mqdsRequest',        action:'exportOpenRequestsData')}", "_blank");
```

Groovy code:

```
List<ExportData> exportData = sObjects?.collect {
            new ExportData(mQDSRequestName: it.mQDSRequestName, name: it.name,   prodID: it.mQDSRequestr?.prodID, mCNforOracleGainTask: it.mQDSRequestr?.mCNforOracleGainTask,
                    lotNumberforOracleGainTask: it.mQDSRequestr?.lotNumberforOracleGainTask,
                    taskType: it.mQDSRequestr?.taskType, currentQuantity: it.mQDSRequestr?.currentQuantity, routeInformation: it.mQDSRequestr?.routeInformation,
                    onHoldReason: it.mQDSRequestr?.onHoldReason, bakeOut: formatDate(date:it.bakeOut, format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a',timeZone: 'PST'),
                    taskCompletion: formatDate(date:it.taskCompletion, format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a',timeZone: 'PST'),
                    taskStatus: it.taskStatus, tISRequestor: it.mQDSRequestr?.tISRequestorr?.name, bakeTime: it.bakeTime, plannerPriority: it.mQDSRequestr?.plannerPriority)
        }

        Map parameters = ["column.widths": Holders.config.standalone.rmaonly.export.file.column.widths]

        exportService.export(fileType, response, fileName, fileExtension, exportData-null, new ArrayList<String>(HEADERS_COLUMNS_STANDALONE_TASKS_RMA_ONLY.keySet()), HEADERS_COLUMNS_STANDALONE_TASKS_RMA_ONLY, [:], parameters)
```

Here, the filename is something like 'BakeStandalonewithRMA=Yes_03022016,0926AMPST'
fileType='excel'
fileExtension='xlsx'

Comment: According to the documentation, yes, it does. What does your code look like?

Comment: I recently used Export plugin 1.6 and just tested again. I can open `.xlsx` fine.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa        I have added my code in the question.

Comment: Found answer. The export plugin does not support 'xlsx' format. 'Excel Export' plugin supports this 'xlsx' format. But I have done that by using XSSFWorkbook as I needed to do styling for each and every column.

Comment: @NaveenGade  what did you mean with your last comment? Does it support it or does it not?